# React-Redux Dispatch Action from Component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to dispatch an action from a button click.

I've created my component.  I connect it to the store that is passed down to the component by a Provider.  But I get an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: this.doSearchClick is not a function

I have my imports:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import action_doSearch from '../../actions/searchActions'
```

My component:

```
class SearchForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, doSearchClick) {
    super(props);
    this.search = this.search.bind(this);
    this.doSearchClick = doSearchClick;
  }

  search() {
    this.doSearchClick('bla bla from search');
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.search}>Search</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Not sure if this is required:

```
SearchForm.propTypes = {
  doSearchClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};
```

Finally the `connect` stuff:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    state
  }
};

const mapDispatchToEvents = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    doSearchClick: (searchCriteria) => {
      dispatch(action_doSearch(searchCriteria));
    }
  };
};
const SearchFormConnected = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToEvents
)(SearchForm);
```

At the top level I pass the store down via Provider:

```
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'

const finalCreateStore = compose(
   applyMiddleware(
      middleware,
      thunk
   ),
   DevTools.instrument()
)(createStore);

const store = finalCreateStore(reducer);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    ....
```

I have also tried to achieve this by accessing the store via context (didn't work and might be deprecated) and also using the `@connect` attribute (gave me a similar error).

Comment: The second param of the constructor is `context`, not `doSearchClick`. If you've mapped correctly that should be available at `this.props.doSearchClick`, although this is a strange name for an action.

Comment: It is a misleading name. Mostly a result of me copying from so many different sources and not understanding what is going on.  It should probably be named dispatchSearchAction...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`doSearchClick` will be passed in the props object. So you need to type `props.doSearchClick` to access it.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that. So 'connect' merges together properties?

Comment: Yes, connect merges the objects you return from mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToEvents

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
SearchForm.propTypes = {
   doSearchClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};
```

Means that your SearchForm component is expecting to get a function named doSearchClick as props from its father.

If the father passed this props the child should access it via

```
props.doSearchClick
```